# Approach to secure access to azure media streaming

Tags: azure-media-services

I've uploaded and encoded several videos to windows Azure Media services. How can I provide secure streaming access to subscribers logged into my MVC 4 web site hosted as an Azure service? I basically don't want them to be able to watch a video if they are not signed in?

(I've been reading about Azure Media services and I can't find anything and that usually means I'm missing the obvious!?)

Answer (score 2):

Now you could use AES or PlayReady content protection with Azure Media Services to encrypt your file over the wire. We provide token authentication on top of the key delivery, which ensure only your authorized user could get the content.

For more information, please read my blog post here: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/10/announcing-public-availability-of-azure-media-services-content-protection-services/

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options for you. Currently you can encrypt the video using PlayReady DRM and then use a third party provider such as BuyDRM or EzDRM to handle authentication and DRM license delivery. EzDRM is currently available for purchase via the Azure store. This will provide you the highest degree of protection for your videos. Long term we are looking into more light weight approaches for authentication and video content protection for the cases where protection provided by DRM is not needed. We will post updates to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MediaServices/ when new capabilities are available in Azure Media Services.

Comment: So what you are saying, is currently WAMS has no mechanism to authenticate an inbound request, even though its http. PlayReady and DRM is overkill and simply not required for this scenario. Would a better option be to generate the smooth streaming URL's and timeout with an access policy, it seems to be a poor compromise. It feels like  we should not use WAMS and just serve the content some other way. In which case what other platform can I use?

Comment: @Anthony What I ended up doing was using WAMS for transcoding only, with an Azure VM serving the streams. Requires that you download the stream assets to said VM, which was not what I wanted... but it works and is fairly easy to implement.