# Protect progressive download videos in Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am considering Azure Media Services to host some of my corporate videos so that I can provide them to my users through my corporate website. The reason I am looking for Azure Media Services is because of the **<strike>Progressive Download</strike> Adaptive bitrate streaming** feature.
My plan is to upload the videos to AMS and then use the progressive download locator in the `<video>` tags. I did some demos and it looks fine. 
However the only concern I have is with the URL. The assets are confidential and the security team raised a concern of having the security tokens in the URL. From their perspective anyone who has this URL can download the files, without logging into the corporate site.

I feel like this is how it works and there no other option to secure the assets. Am I correct? Are there any best practices or guideline that I can use to secure these Azure hosted assets?

My goal is to restrict the possibility of a user (or a hacker) directly accessing the files with the URL seen in the HTML source (the `<video>` tag's `src` attribute).

Comment: Looks like for progressive download I don't have any security.

Comment: Found an older question but not yet answered. Also I believe there are changes in AMS since that question is  posted.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257540/approach-to-secure-access-to-azure-media-streaming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this scenario, it's best to secure the video content with a content protection such as AES-128 clear key encryption. For corporate network videos (trusted end-users) the content is encrypted from access by a third-party and setting up encryption is simple. Have a look at the public docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-protect-with-aes128

Comment: I have to agree with Dwyane. For progressive download, I have not found any workaround  and I ended up using adaptive bitrate streaming instead of progressive download.